# Are uniforms actually defined in THREE.js RawShaderMaterial?

Tags: javascript, three.js

The [documentation](http://threejs.org/docs/#) for the THREE.Js RawShaderMaterial says:

> built-in uniforms and attributes are not automatically prepended to the GLSL shader code.

However, in practice I am able to run the following shader, with a rawShaderMaterial:

```
    <script type="x-shader/x-vertex" id="vertexShader">                                                                                                                                                                             
     precision mediump float;                                                                                                                                                                                                       
     precision mediump int;                                                                                                                                                                                                         

     uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix;                                                                                                                                                                                                  
     uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;                                                                                                                                                                                                 

     attribute vec3 position;                                                                                                                                                                                                       
     attribute vec4 color;                                                                                                                                                                                                          

     varying vec3 vPosition;                                                                                                                                                                                                        
     varying vec4 vColor;                                                                                                                                                                                                           


      void main() {                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
        vPosition = position;                                                                                                                                                                                                       
        vColor = color;                                                                                                                                                                                                             

        gl_Position = projectionMatrix *                                                                                                                                                                                            
                      modelViewMatrix *                                                                                                                                                                                             
                      vec4(position.x, position.y, position.z, 1.0);                                                                                                                                                                
        }
```

Without defining the `modelViewMatrix` or `projectionMatrix` anywhere.  Are some uniforms actually are passed to the rawshader material after all?

Comment: you should be getting an error (at least on Chrome) when not defining `modelViewMatrix` and `projectionMatrix` (and others) and using a `RawShaderMaterial`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes,

```
uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix;                                                                                                                                                                                                  
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 modelMatrix;
uniform mat4 viewMatrix;
uniform mat3 normalMatrix;
uniform vec3 cameraPosition;
```

are available to you when using `RawShaderMaterial`, however you must declare them in your shader if you want to use them. They are not automatically prefixed.

three.js r.73

Comment: I don't like using comments for appreciating an answer, but this was really helpful. I wonder what part of the documentation I have interpreted incompletely

Comment: Here is a complete list of the built-in variables: https://threejs.org/docs/?q=Shaderma#api/en/renderers/webgl/WebGLProgram The three built-in attributes are: attribute vec3 position;
attribute vec3 normal;
attribute vec2 uv;